# What are the right data types to make a function that copies between iterators in Rust as versatile as possible?

Tags: types, rust, iterator

I commonly need to copy data between two iterables. Apart from the [special case of slices](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.clone_from_slice), I found no suitable function in the standard library, so I tried writing my own one:

```
fn copy(source: /* ? */, target: /* ? */) {
    for (s, t) in source.zip(target) {
        *t = s.clone();
    }
}
```

What would be the right choice of data types to make this function as versatile as possible?

Comment: Could you provide an example when you would use this operation? In particular, what would be your target iterator if it's not a slice?

Comment: I think a much more common use case is covered by the [`Extend` trait](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Extend.html). Maybe this is what you are looking for?

Comment: @SvenMarnach An example target would be https://docs.rs/petgraph/0.5.1/petgraph/graph/struct.Graph.html#method.node_weights_mut .

Comment: I guess that can make sense, but it seems rare, and I'd decide on a case-by-case basis whether to prefer imperative style.

Comment: I'm guessing your experience is mostly with C++? Rust iterators are more closely related to iterators in Python or other modern languages, rather than C++ (generator-like instead of cursor-like). You *can* do "output iterators" in Rust, as Masklinn's answer shows, but it's not a usual way to do things. I suspect most Rustaceans would just write the loop.

Comment: why not just implement `clone()`? It will do exactly what you want without messin' up with iterators.

Comment: @Sugar Can you explain how that will help? Lets say for example `source` is an iterator to a Vec and `target` an iterator to a set of nodes in a tree.

Comment: @trentcl Not true but certainly more C++ than Rust :) But it seems to me every `Iterator<mut&>` is precisely an "output iterator". And the loop still uses "output iterators", it's just less explicit than in the function signature.

Comment: @wonce if you require type conversion it must implement `Into` trait, not fiddle with iterators and pointers, Otherwise, it is required to prepare target container to have enough memory before copy or you have a chance to break iterator on relocation, for example. if there's no type conversion it is enough to implement only `clone`. Iterators should not be modified in idiomatic Rust the way you meant to.

Comment: @Sugar Type conversion from the source container to the target container is not sensible here since the target container contains additional data not reflected in the source. The target iterator just iterates over some part of the container.
Also this is about updating an *existing* target, not constructing a new one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ```
> s.clone()
> ```

that doesn't seem super useful as it limits you to clonable input items. The caller can just use `cloned()` or `copied()` to adapt the iterator.

The only really necessary constraint should be that you can assign source items to target items.

I guess it'd look something like

```rust
fn copy<S, SI, T, TI>(source: S, target: T)
where
    S: Iterator<Item = SI>,
    T: Iterator<Item = TI>,
    TI: DerefMut<Target = SI>,
{
    for (s, mut t) in source.zip(target) {
        *t = s;
    }
}
```

but frankly for the rare cases I need to do such a thing I'd rather just write the imperative loop.

Comment: `IntoIterator` would make this more general (lets you do stuff like `copy(foo, &mut bar)` instead of `copy(foo.into_iter(), bar.iter_mut())`).

Comment: I strongly disagree. It would make this more *convenient* for the caller as you could pass it any `IntoIterator` but it would not change the capabilities of the function, just complexify the signature and increase code bloat.

Comment: Fair point, it does not really make the function more general in that sense because you can always put `.into_iter` in the caller, but it does not make the signature any more complex (it's literally just changing `Iterator` to `IntoIterator`), and I'm not sure in what respect it causes bloat. That seems to me 1 good reason to prefer `IntoIterator` and no good reason to prefer `Iterator` here.